# ApostropheCMS Docker Image Issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, content-management-system, apostrophe-cms

I am trying to install aposcms using docker. I am following the exact steps as in their [official documentation](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/docker.html#make-a-dockerfile) and when I repeat the step for `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

`ERROR: no such image: aposDockerImageFileName:latest: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase`

Clearly the issue is in line 12 of the `.yml` file but I can't find a solution for it and i have searched everywhere.

Any thoughts regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

the documentation as it stands is indeed not very clear.

The problem is that you have to

- [build your own Dockerfile](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/docker.html#make-a-dockerfile),
- [build the image](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/docker.html#build-the-image),
- name it properly (still part of the previous link)
- [use that name in the docker-compose.yml](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/howtos/docker.html#example-docker-compose-yml)

OR

add the `build` subsection in the docker-compose.yml and change the image name.

e.g.

```yaml
[...]
  aposcms:
    build:
      context: ./path_to_apos/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "my_apos_docker_image:0.0.1"
```

Comment: thank you this help me understand what the issue was. there documentation is lacking so many things... i keep getting one error after another

Comment: Apostrophe core team dev here. We're in the midst of getting the next major version out in an alpha release, but we do want to do more work on the documentation as soon as we can. It would *really* help if you could open an issue in the apostrophe-documentation repo with specifics on how that page is falling short. We don't have a big team, so we're depending on the community to help identify the gaps and make the time we do have most effective. Thanks!

Comment: @alexbea: I've created a PR concerning this topic.

Comment: Thank you very much!